# How to use SQL to find specific names or words in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a database of data from Reddit. I want to find the name and description of all subreddits where the name starts with "covid" or "corona" and the description contains "covid" anywhere. I then want to output a table that has two columns: name and description.

So far, I have tried this SQL code:

```
select 
    subreddit AS name,
    subreddit AS description
    from
    subreddit
    where subr_description like "%covid%" "%corona%";
```

When I execute, I get an output of the table with the appropriate columns: name and description but they are empty, no data.

How can I have the table with the right columns populated with the right data please?

Comment: Yes, I have a table named "subreddit" as well as a column with the same name. If it helps, the subreddit table has the following columns: subreddit, subr_created_at, subr_description, subr_faved_by, subr_numb_members, subr_numb_posts.

Comment: Thanks. When asking database questions, it's always beneficial to include the table schema so we can see column names and types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to adjust the column names that you're selecting instead of `subreddit AS x` twice. I'm not sure if you even have a column named `subreddit` or not, but that also appears to be the table name, which is confusing.

Then you can adjust the logic in the `WHERE` to check your two conditions:

```
SELECT
    subreddit AS name,
    subr_description AS description
FROM
    subreddit
WHERE
    -- name starts with covid or corona ("text%")
    (subreddit LIKE "covid%" OR subreddit LIKE "corona%")
    -- description contains covid ("%text%")
    AND subr_description LIKE "%covid%"
```

Comment: @OceanWaves Note that the `"text%"` format equates to "starts with `text`", and `"%text%"` format equates to "contains `text`". Also, including parenthesis is always recommended when mixing AND and OR to make it apparent how the logic should work. Otherwise, it's not obvious if you mean `x OR (y AND z)` or `(x OR y) AND z`. I have updated my answer to align with your column names.